# updating a value in main after updating it in a function , without pointers

Tags: c, function

im trying to update values in main according to what changes were made in a function without using pointers

im working on a snake game and to make a move i send the row and column of both the head and the tail to a void function , and inside of it i change them according to what move was made , but they are not updated in main and therefor the next move wont be donr correctly , how can i update them in main but without using pointers ?(its a homework , they specified not using pointers)
the code below is for one case which is when the player wants to move down (2 is foe down) and at the end i changed the column of the tail and the row of the head, but it dosent update them in main for when i send the next move

```
if(move==2){
   if (board[head_row+1][head_cal] != 0) 
            {print_finsih_msg(player,ILLEGAL_MOVE);exit(0);}
   if(head_row == tail_row && head_cal < tail_cal) {               
            board[head_row+1][head_cal] = SHTRODEL_HEAD ; 
            board[head_row][head_cal] = '+' ;
            board[tail_row][tail_cal] = 0;
            tail_cal--;
            head_row++;}
```

so for examble if the next move is 6 - right it will print that the move is illegal because it still has that the head has its body on the right

Comment: You could either pass the numbers in an array, change the values in side the array ... If that's still too pointerish, you could pass and return a struct (by value).

Comment: Show a minimal complete example.

Comment: A not recommend way of "solving" this problem would be to use global variables. But that's a bad practice in most cases

Comment: Do the function *have* to be `void`? Can it be modified to return something?

Answer (score 1):

C offers three general ways of communicating values back to the calling function:

1. **Returning a value** - This is the most common way of providing data back for primitive types. However, you are allowed to make a `struct` type, and return it to the caller.
2. **Passing a pointer** - This is common for situations when multiple variables need to be modified.
3. **Using variables visible to both the caller function and the function being called** - these could be static or global variables.

Note that it is not enough to keep a position for the head and the tail of the snake: you need to store all positions occupied by your snake in order to be able to advance its tail to the next step. This could be easily implemented with a [*Circular Buffer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) sized at the maximum length of the snake:

```
static int snake_row[MAX_LENGTH+1];
static int snake_col[MAX_LENGTH+1];
static int snake_head = 0;
static int snake_tail = 0;
```

Arrays `snake_row` and `snake_col` between indexes `snake_head` and `snake_tail` represent positions currently occupied by the snake. This makes `board[][]` optional, because you can check for self-crossing by iterating the buffer.